# How to set values of entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have module which is not mapped to database( sql server) and is only use to generate report.

```
public class Report
{
    public int USERID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateToCal { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? Intime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan?  OutTime { get; set; }
}
```

I generate a query and fill some properties(USERID, DateToCal, Name, Position, Intime) of `Report` and some properties of Report remains null ( as `OutTime is null`)

```
var query = .....;
```

Now what I want iterate on items of query( of type `Report`) and set value for null properties `OutTime` as

```
foreach(var items in query)
            {
                var outtime= from x in con.CHECKINOUTs
                              where x.USERID == items.USERID && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CHECKTIME) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(items.DateToCal && x.CHECKTYPE == "O"
                              select x.CHECKTIME
                              .Single();
                items.OutTime= outtime.TimeOfDay;
            }
```

Now problem is, on mousehover to `items.OutTime` with in foreach there appear value but if I out from foreach and mousehover to `query` there is still `OutTime is null`. There not appear value what I set. Is this is possible to set value of entities such way. Or what is my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Once you set the value, it should not be overwritten. Its strange.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save query results locally before iterating over them:

```
 var query = ....ToList();
```

Looks like in your case query executed two times - first time when you are updating `OutTime` property, and second time when you are iterating over query items (either looking in debugger or displaying in UI). So, when query executed second time, you see completely new set of objects as query result (which have original `null` values of `OutTime`).

BTW Consider to use single JOIN query instead of making separate outtime query for each item in your main query.

Comment: First of all thank you for response. I try using JOIN but since both InTime and OutTime are from model CHECKINOUT's CHECKTIME depending on CHECKTYPE( either I or O ). If CHECKTYPE is I CHECKTIME will be InTime and if CHECKTYPE is O CHECKTIME will be OutTime. I can't check CHECKTYPE for both I and O on same query so I use subquery. Is there any other way to do this. Please suggest me I am having problem.

Comment: @link2jagann OK, I'll think about join query, but you need to provide your `query` definition. Have my answer solved your problem?

Comment: No. Is there any other way using List or something?

Comment: O wait it seems it is working ( previously i made some changes so it was not worked) . Thank you very much. I don't know how/why i missed .ToList() on query.

Answer (score 0):

Try code something like this:

```
public class Report
{
    public int USERID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateToCal { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan? _intime;
    public TimeSpan Intime {
        get { return _intime ?? new TimeSpan(0); }  
        set { _intime = value; }
    }
    private TimeSpan? _outTime;
    public TimeSpan OutTime
    {
        get { return _outTime ?? new TimeSpan(0); }
        set { _outTime = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same issue nothing change.